# Python print every possibility of setences

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I wrote a simple sentence generator made out of lists.

```
a_a = ['Hey, ', 'Hello, ', 'Hi, ']
a_b = 'this is a random sentence! '
a_c = ['Bye! ', 'Bye, bye! ', 'Goodbye! ']

sentence = a_a[secrets.randbelow(3)] + a_b + a_c[secrets.randbelow(3)]
```

The real code is much bigger. I need a way to print out every possible sentence or safe it to a text file. Can someone help me? I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just plain python:

```py
a_a = ['Hey, ', 'Hello, ', 'Hi, ']
a_b = 'this is a random sentence! '
a_c = ['Bye! ', 'Bye, bye! ', 'Goodbye! ']

for element_a in a_a:
    for element_c in a_c:
        print(element_a + a_b + element_c)
```

Using `itertools` to get to a single loop that iterates over all combinations:

```py
import itertools

a_a = ['Hey, ', 'Hello, ', 'Hi, ']
a_b = 'this is a random sentence! '
a_c = ['Bye! ', 'Bye, bye! ', 'Goodbye! ']

for element_a, element_c in itertools.product(a_a, a_c):
    print(element_a + a_b + element_c)
```

If you want to save it to a file, replace the `print` statement with something else, like the command to write the combination to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within default python do this:

```
a_a = ['Hey, ', 'Hello, ', 'Hi, ']
a_b = 'this is a random sentence! '
a_c = ['Bye! ', 'Bye, bye! ', 'Goodbye! ']

sentence = a_a[secrets.randbelow(3)] + a_b + a_c[secrets.randbelow(3)]

##added code
ops1 = len(a_a)
ops2 = len(a_c)
allOps = ops1 * ops2

index1 = 0
index2 = 0

for allOps in range(0, allOps):
    post = a_a[index1] + a_c[index2]
    print(post)
    index2+=1
    if index2 == ops2:
        index2 = 0
        index1+=1
```

This code is copy and pastable and requires no additions like intertools

Alt if you are not in school:

```
for element_num in num:
    for element_let in let:
        print(element_num + element_let)
```